# PHP - Date format being read as m/j/Y instead of d/m/Y

Tags: php, date, post, string-formatting, date-format

I am attempting to populate a table with values listed by date using PHP. I set the value of my dateSelected variable to $_POST and have the date range picker set to DD/MM/YYYY. Below is the setting of variable.

```
   if ( isset($_POST['date'])){
$DateSelected = $_POST['date'];
}else {
unset($DateSelected);
$DateSelected = date('j/m/Y');
}
```

The only time I can display my table is when I flip the format during the call of the function in the controller. Like below -

```
    GetHourlyPerformance(DateTime::createFromFormat('m/j/Y',
    $DateSelected)->format('j/m/Y')
```

Obviously when I select a row that has a day after the 12th of the month. Nothing will be returned. I for the life of me cannot figure out where I am going wrong or where I should format the date. As it is now without the re-format at the controller it reads as m/j/Y.

The var_dump for the $_POST variable is as follows -

```
    array(4) { ["workcenter"]=> string(2) "15" ["Week"]=> string(2) "37" ["date"]=> string(10) "11/09/2016" ["Shift"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

So the date string is being read correctly, yet nothing displays in the table.

```
    <?php
    function GetHourlySumary($date,$Workcenter, $Shift){
    try {
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=etaddressOfTargt;     Database=CPB','$dbn','$db');

    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM HourlySummary WHERE Workcentre = (?) AND Shift = (?) AND  ProductionDate= (?) order by ProcessDate , ProcessHour" ;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);


    $params = array($Workcenter,$Shift, $date);

    $stmt->execute($params);

    $cuRow = 0; 
    $toReturn = array(); 

    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {

            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["Shift"] = $row['Shift'] ; 
            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["Hour"] =  $row['ProcessHour'] ; 
            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["Quantity Produced"] = $row['QuantityProduced'] ; 
            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["No WIPS"]  =  $row['ReelsProduced'] ; 
            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["Reams Produced"]=   $row['ReamsOut'] ; 
            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["Quantity Broke"]  =  $row['QuantityBroke'] ; 
            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["Target Broke"]  =  $row['TargetBroke'] ; 
            $toReturn [$cuRow] ["Mins Down"]  =  $row['MinutesDown'] ; 
        $cuRow++; 
    }



    $dbh = null;    
    return $toReturn;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

}
?>
```

Above is the code for the model of and below is the view - Somewhere in there the value of $dateSelected changes.

```
    <div class="container">
    <form method= 'post' action= "" id = "form">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-2'>
                Workcentre  : 
                <SELECT name="workcenter" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($Workcenters);$i++)
                    {
                        if ($i == $WorkcenterSelected ) $selected = 'selected'; 
                        else $selected = '';
echo "<option value = {$i} {$selected}>{$Workcenters[$i]} </option>";}?>
                </SELECT>
            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-2'>
                Week  : 
                <SELECT name="Week" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= date('W');$i++)
                    {
                        if ($i == $WeekSelected ) $selected = 'selected'; 
                        else $selected = '';
                        echo "<option value = {$i} {$selected}> Week {$i} </option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </SELECT>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-4'></div>
            <input type="text" id = "selectDate" name='date' class="form-control" style= "display: inline" value=<?php echo $DateSelected?> />

            <input type="text" id = "selectShift" name='Shift' class="form-control" style= "display: none" value=<?php echo $ShiftSelected?> />

            <div class='col-md-4'> 
                <?php if(isStatusUp($Workcenters[$WorkcenterSelected]))
                {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" style="text-align:center;">
                    <strong>Status :</strong> Up
                    </div>'; 
                }else{
                    $Status = getStatus($Workcenters[$WorkcenterSelected]);
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='text-align:center;'>
                        <strong>Status :</strong> ".$Status."
                    </div>"; 
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<br/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <tr>
       <th>Shift</th>
       <th>QTY Produced</th>
       <th>No. of WIPs</th>
       <th>Reams Produced</th>
       <th>QTY Broke</th>
       <th>Target Broke</th>
       <th>Mins Down</th>

   </tr>
   <?php 

   foreach ($ShiftSumaryTab as &$row)
   {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['Production Date']);
        echo
        "<tr class='table-row' data-date={$date->format('d/m/Y')} data-shift ={$row['Shift']} >
                <td>{$row['Shift']} {$date->format('D M-d')} </td>
                <td>{$row['Quantity Produced']}</td>
                <td>{$row['No WIPS']}</td>
                <td>{$row['Reams Produced']}</td>
                <td>{$row['Quantity Broke']}</td>
                <td>{$row['Target Broke']}</td>
                <td>{$row['Minutes Down']}</td>

            </tr>";
   }
    echo
        "
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#b3d9ff'><strong> Week : {$WeekSelected} </strong></td>
            <td bgcolor='#b3d9ff'><strong> {$SumShiftSumaryTab['Quantity Produced']}</strong></td>
            <td bgcolor='#b3d9ff'><strong> {$SumShiftSumaryTab['No WIPS']}</strong></td>
            <td bgcolor='#b3d9ff'><strong> {$SumShiftSumaryTab['Reams Produced']}</strong></td>
            <td bgcolor='#b3d9ff'><strong> {$SumShiftSumaryTab['Quantity Broke']}</strong></td>
            <td bgcolor='#b3d9ff'><strong> {$SumShiftSumaryTab['Target Broke']}</strong></td>
            <td bgcolor='#b3d9ff'><strong> {$SumShiftSumaryTab['Minutes Down']}</strong></td>

        </tr>";
   ?>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function() {
$(".table-row").click(function() {
    $("#form").attr('action', '?action=HS');
    $("#selectDate").val($(this).data("date"));
    $("#selectShift").val($(this).data("Shift"));
    $("#form").submit();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is your **exact** problem? You use `createFromFormat('m/j/Y'` so it is `m/j/y` instead of `d/m/Y`. I don't understand your problem

Comment: If your datepicker is set for `dd/m/yyyy`, then why are you using `createFromFormat('m(month)/j(day)/Y(year)`?

Comment: ^^ I believe OP is saying it doesn't display correctly unless they use the `createFromFormat('m/j/Y')`.  To the OP: Please post the rest of your code, especially the table you discuss.

Comment: Normaly DATE Format in Database are `Y-m-d` (this can be sorted as string) not with `/`, and do you read about missing leading zeros if you are using `j` instead of `d` ?

Comment: And also post a var_dump of `$_POST['date']` to see exactly how it's passing through.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for the responses. As Devon says I have to use createFromFormat in the controller as this is the only way I will see results, as if the setting of $dateSelected to j/m/Y is ignored or lost somewhere. I have changed j/m/Y to d/m/Y.

Comment: @Devon - I have added in the necessary code that I believe is causing the problem - I have also added in the var dump. Any help is once again very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, it was formatted wrongly when performing the query, changed the format to read Y-m-d and there we have it.

```
$HourlyPerformanceTab = 
GetHourlyPerformance(DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$DateSelected)->format('Y-m-d'),
$Workcenters[$WorkcenterSelected], $Hours[ $HourSelected] );
```